# How "sudo !!" works in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

How "sudo !!" works in bash:

```
$ touch /bin/1
touch: cannot touch `/bin/1': Permission denied
$ sudo !!
sudo touch /bin/1
```

Comment: Are you asking how sudo changes things, or hot the "!!" is expanded, or both?  ooshro gives a very nice explanation for the !!-expansion, below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bash support a history expansion feature. History expansions are implemented by the '!'. '!!' refer to the previous command.

History expansion is performed immediately after a command line is read, before execve() system call.

```
$ touch /bin/1
touch: невозможно выполнить touch для «/bin/1»: Отказано в доступе
$ sudo strace !!                
sudo strace touch /bin/1
execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "/bin/1"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
```

bash expansion "sudo !!" to "sudo touch /bin/1" and then run command.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo !!` is just telling the terminal to run the previous command, but this time under sudo. In this case it is the same as just typeing `sudo touch /bin/1` the first time.